# inner join and separate by a forward slash using Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to inner join  sbd.Dosage and sbd.Units into one column and add a / between them after the inner join.

EX sbd.Dosage + / + sbd.Units

```
 select sbd.Code, c.Description, sbd.Dosage, Case when sbd.Units = '' then '1' else sbd.Units end as Units, 
        ad.ApptDate, sbd.RCycle, sbd.RWeek, sbd.RDay, t.HistoryOrder, t.TypeId
    from bill_SuperBillDetail sbd, bill_ProcedureVerification pv, AppointmentData ad,
        CPTCode c, CPTType t
    where sbd.AccessionNumber = pv.AccessionNumber
        and pv.ApptId = ad.ApptId
        and ad.PatientId = 443
        and ad.ApptDate <= GETDATE()
        and ad.ApptDate > 31
        and sbd.Code = c.Code
        and c.TypeId = t.TypeId
```

Comment: Do you mean: `sbd.Dosage || '/' || sbd.Units`

Comment: For T-SQL, just add another column: `sbd.Dosage + '/' + sbd.Units AS DosagePerUnits`

Comment: all i want to do is inner joing sbd.Dosage and sbd.Units add a / between them when the select statement is called

Comment: Yes, did you try what they suggested:  `select sbd.Dosage + '/' + sbd.Units AS DosagePerUnits...` with the rest of your SQL statement?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, the concatonation operator for tsql is a plus sign (+).  The double pipe (||) are appropriate for oracle, ColdFusion Query of Queries, and probably others.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Well, to be fair, `||` *is* the SQL:2008 standard.

Comment: Plus for `+` solution. `||` is logic operator for C(#)/(t)SQL people.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an open question however I believe you are looking for,

Assuming that both the Dosage and Unit columns are char based then the below should get you what you want,

```
sbd.Dosage + '/' + (Case when sbd.Units = '' then '1' else sbd.Units END) AS [Dosage/Units]
```

If Dosage or units aren't then you may need to look at converting to ensure that everything behaves.